# Menu Bar of Angular Application (menu with user wise right) sometimes shows extra icons and sometimes doesn't

Tags: angular

I am working on angular app in which we have to maintain user rights. Issue is that sometimes side menu show icons (which are basically routes to different pages) and sometimes side menu do not show icons that must be there.
Let's say I have three or more Ids with different screen rights. When I open browser for the first time and Login with one Id menu is generated just fine and there is no less or no more icons (routes to pages). I logout and Login with different Id then either of the following happens:
1. Side menu have icons from the previous user rights
2. Or it shows icons for both of user.
I have been searching the web for this issue but found nothing or I would say I couldn't reach any solution. Please help me its my first project.

User Rights are fetched from database and are rendered with for loop in html in angular.

Comment: Someone suggested to Press F5 after log in and it really worked but question is why do I need to manually press f5 ? Isn't there any programatic way to solve this issue?

Comment: Hello, I think you should show some code, because it's very hard to grasp your problem with only this description. How do you deal with the rights ? Is there a service ? Does it expose an Observable ? ... etc